# MySQL Query to XML output

Tags: java, mysql, xml

Is there a framework current out there that allows you to take MYSQL query output and convert it all into XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
 echo 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' | mysql --xml
```

yields:

```
 <resultset statement="SELECT ....">
   <row>
     <field name="TABLE_NAME">CHARACTER_SETS</field>
     ...
   </row>
 </resultset>
```

If you want to do it with Java, you could try `javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet.writeXml(ResultSet, Writer)`. Unfortunately, i don't know of any other implementations than Sun-specific `com.sun.rowset.WebRowSetImpl`

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with plain Java objects, you could use XStream. 
So you would need to get the JDBC result set into some plain java object and then serialize it to XML using this.

http://x-stream.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

Two completely separate problems: querying a database and serializing to XML.  Treat them separately and you'll have better luck.